# Elasticsearch Query Filter Less Than Equals to Null Field

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have codes like this:

```
case "promo":
            productFitlerQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("itemVariants.priceDetail.totalPromoPercentage").gt(0));
            break;
case "-promo":
            productFitlerQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("itemVariants.priceDetail.totalPromoPercentage").lte(0));
            break;
```

It's filtering the result by totalPromoPercentage field which sometimes can be null.
Is my code already proper to handle null possibility? Or is null already handled and converted to 0 by ElasticSearch?

If you guys have ElasticSearch documentation, it will be very helpful.

Comment: My advice is to test on known data. Sometimes ELK stacks manage empty strings, null or missing values in non-consistent ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid null data in your output you can filter the data using exists query before the range query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "user"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So I need to do two queries? First, check the existence of the field, and second, the range query?